# Word Replace in C, not Substring

Tags: c

Is there a way to replace all occurrences of a word in a string in C with another word. By word, I don't mean substring.

Here's what I want to achieve:

Input String:

```
OneOne One One OneOneOne One
```

Word to find:

```
One
```

Word to Replace it with:

```
Forty
```

Desired Output:

```
OneOne Forty Forty OneOneOne Forty
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

there are many example functions for replacing words in a string, i.e. [What is the function to replace string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

you can use these functions to do what you want because the *(white)spaces are also characters*, see [Removing Spaces from a String in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726302/removing-spaces-from-a-string-in-c) and https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

so in the replace functions it is a difference if the replace string is

`replace ='One'` or `replace = ' One '`

if you use the second this should work

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

[Unicode stored in C char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017328/unicode-stored-in-c-char)